# What's the mechanism for the oxidation of primary alcohol to carboxylic acid with HNO3?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Can someone help me find the mechanism for this reaction. I've been looking for it, but I 
haven't found it. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. I do not think this is a homework question, but a few people have voted to close your question because it violates the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). Would you be willing to improve your question with some additional details, like what your thoughts are or where you have tried looking?

Answer (score 1):

http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/25511593/oxidation-nitric-acid-aliphatic-alcohols-diols-carboxylic-acids

http://pages.towson.edu/ladon/orgrxs/reagent/oxidizer.htm

It is a dangerous thing to do for the easy detonation of nitrate esters.  Activated and stabilized alcohols, e.g., benzoin to benzil, are reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The reaction starts with the formation of an organic nitric acid ester (as these compounds are dangerously unstable, as Uncle Al already pointed out, I would not recommend to use nitric acid for this oxidation). The negatively charged nitrate oxygen abstracts an alpha proton from the alkyl group, and $\ce{HNO2}$ is eliminated, yielding the aldehyde. Nucleophilic attack of nitrate on the carbonyl group and subsequent elimination of another equivalent $\ce{HNO2}$ finally yields the carboxylate.